# Notes error: Could not open the ID file in lotus notes

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Please somebody help me. I use Lotus Notes to send email with using vb.net but I got this error when I try to run. I already add references about interop.lotus.dll and interop.Domino.dll but it's still the same error. Please advice..

```
Line 115:        If dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
Line 116:            **s.Initialize("abcde!")** 'ERROR in THIS LINE




Protected Sub btnSend_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.ServerClick
    Dim s As New Domino.NotesSession
    Dim db As Domino.NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As Domino.NotesDocument
    Dim mimeEntity As Domino.NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim mimeChild As Domino.NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim header As Domino.NotesMIMEHeader
    Dim stream As Domino.NotesStream
    Dim sendTo As String
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=[hide];User ID=[hide];initial Catalog=[hide];Password=[hide]"
    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    objConn.Open()
    Dim dsEmail = New DataSet
    Dim CommTaskA As SqlCommand
    Dim AdapTaskA As SqlDataAdapter
    CommTaskA = New SqlCommand("select EMAILBLASTCCID, rtrim(ltrim(EMAILADDR)) EMAILADDR, SUBJECTEMAIL, EMAILTEMPLATE from [hide] where [MESSAGE_TIME] is NULL", objConn)
    CommTaskA.CommandTimeout = 180
    AdapTaskA = New SqlDataAdapter
    AdapTaskA.SelectCommand = CommTaskA
    AdapTaskA.Fill(dsEmail)
    AdapTaskA.Dispose()
    CommTaskA.Dispose()
    objConn.Close()
    If dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        s.Initialize("abcde!")
         db = s.GetDatabase("[hide]", "[hide].nsf", False)
        subjectEmail = dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString
        For x As Integer = 0 To dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            doc = db.CreateDocument()
            sendTo = dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows(x)(1).ToString
            doc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows(x)(1))
            doc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows(x)(2))

            mimeEntity = doc.CreateMIMEEntity
            mimeChild = mimeEntity.CreateChildEntity
            header = mimeEntity.GetNthHeader("Content-Type")
            header.SetHeaderVal("multipart/related")

            stream = s.CreateStream
            stream.WriteText("<img src='" & dsEmail.Tables(0).Rows(x)(3) & "'>")

            mimeChild.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/html", Domino.MIME_ENCODING.ENC_NONE)
            stream.Close()

            doc.Send(False)
            objConn.Open()
            CommTaskA = New SqlCommand("update [ZITA].[DEV].[EMAILBLASTCC_test] set [MESSAGE_TIME] ='" & DateTime.Now.ToString & "'  where rtrim(ltrim(EMAILADDR)) = '" & sendTo & "'", objConn)
            CommTaskA.CommandTimeout = 180
            CommTaskA.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CommTaskA.Dispose()
            objConn.Close()
        Next


    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: we are going to need more code... what is s?

Comment: oh ok ok I am sorry this is s 

Dim s As New Domino.NotesSession

Any Advice??

Comment: Based on http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_INITIALIZE_METHOD_SESSION_COM.html the initialise method is passed a password. Please check that the password is correct... if it is we will need to see more code regarding the connection.

Comment: Thank you mych for your response but I really sure the password is correct because I already login to IBM lotus notes with this password..

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your respond.. I found the answer
the problem because the **user account** Lotus Notes and my IIS Manager are **different**.
You must make your **Lotus Notes IBM** and **Application Pool Identity in IIS Manager** run with the same account.
It works for me. Thank You

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the Windows environment variable `PATH` points to `C:\Users\adventina.nababan\AppData\Local\IBM\Notes\Data\` too.

For further instructions on how to do this, please take a look at the question "[Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546324/4464702)".